# I am having an issue to get a string method to work

Tags: javascript, java

When I run this code, it just prints `listlist pre-requisite 1 pre-requisite 2`. And it does not allow for the user to input `prerequisite 1`
And `prerequisite 2`. Please help.

```
public static String Info(Scanner my)
{
     System.out.println(“How many pre-requisites does the course     
         have”);        
         Int NumPreReq1= my.nextInt();
         For ( i=1; i<=NumPreReq1; I++){
             System.out.println(“list pre-requisite 1”);
             String PreReq = my.nextLine();
         }
       Return PreReq; 
 }
```

Comment: Why this question has `javascript` tag?

Comment: ........`For`?? `Int`?? Please post *real* code only

Comment: ........`Return`??

Comment: Overlooking the obvious syntax errors, it might be that you've entered a number before calling method `info()`, so how about you clear the buffer at the start? i.e. `my.nextLine();` then `int NumPreReq1= my.nextInt();` And yes, `my.nextLine();` is a valid statement, so just type it as is then your code.

Comment: And to that end, please post the code for the method where you call `info()`

Comment: Please fix your syntax errors first.

Answer (score 0):

Try my.next()

Hope this helps....